# React stack navigation automatically starts first screen

Tags: react-native

I have a following stack and switch navigator. Here is code:

**Parent Stack**

```
const ParentStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Screen1,
    Screen2,
    Screen3,
  },
  {headerMode: 'none', initialRouteName: 'Screen1'},
);
```

**User Stack**

```
const UserStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Screen11,
    Screen22,
    Screen33,
  },
  {headerMode: 'none', initialRouteName: 'Screen11'},
);
```

**Switch Stack**

```
    const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    Auth,
    ParentStack,
    UserStack,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Auth',
  },
);
```

When I am on 'Auth' Screen, and I start the `Screen2` using below code:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen2')
```

Screen2 started successfully. But when I press Back, then Screen1 also present in stack. But I had only started the Screen2.

- Is this default react native behavior to start the first screen in stack automatically?
- Is there any way to start only Screen2?

Comment: Yes, because you are redirecting from `screen1` to `screen2` so `screen1` is there in stack

Comment: @Ravi But I started `Screen2` from `Auth`. So why `Screen1` started, just because of first entry in stack?

Comment: you can change it through `initialRouteName` in `Auth` stack

Answer (score 0):

`import {NavigationActions, StackActions} from 'react-navigation';`

```
const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
          index: 0,
          actions: [
            NavigationActions.navigate({routeName: 'your_screen_name'}), //MainTabbarScreen NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'MainTabbarScreen' })//Login
          ],
        });
        this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

Use above code while you navigate to screen2.

Comment: Above code will work, if you are in same stack. But as you see `Auth` screen outside the `ParentStack`, and when I tried to `reset` as per your example. I got `Error: There is no route defined for key Screen2 ..... ......`.